# Select an ID where there is only one row and that row is a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have this query. There's a lot of joins because I am checking if an ID is linked to any of those tables.

Currently, this query shows me any ID's that are not linked to any of those tables. I would like to add to it so that it also shows any IDs that are linked to the d table, but only if there is only 1 row in the D table and the type in the D field is 'member'.

```
SELECT 
    c.ID,
    c.location,
    c.pb,
    c.name,
    c.surname

FROM c
    LEFT JOIN l on c.rowno = l.rowno
    LEFT JOIN d on c.rowno = d.rowno
    LEFT JOIN t on c.rowno = t.rowno
    LEFT JOIN cj ON (c.rowno = cj.rowno OR c.rowno = cj.rowno2)
    LEFT JOIN dj ON c.rowno = d.rowno
    LEFT JOIN lg ON c.rowno = lg.rowno
    LEFT JOIN tj ON c.rowno = tj.rowno

WHERE
    c.status != 'closed'
    AND l.rowno IS NULL
    AND d.rowno IS NULL
    AND t.rowno IS NULL
    AND cj.rowno IS NULL
    AND dj.rowno IS NULL
    AND lg.rowno IS NULL
    AND tj.rowno IS NULL
```

My first thought is to just add

```
WHERE D.type = 'member'
```

But that gives me all IDs that have a row with D.type = member (they could have 10 rows with all different types, but as long as 1 of those has type = member it shows up). I want to see ID's that ONLY have d.type = member

I'm sorry if I'm wording this badly, I'm having trouble getting this straight in my head. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See what happens if you put that condition in the ON clause instead.

Comment: you state/imply that your query shows tables with related rows based on ID, but all of your joins are based on a different field  (rowno), so your query is showing relationships based on rowno.   what is rowno?

Comment: rowno is the PK, although the ID is also a unique field. for our database rowno is a very long number, so we have ID as a more reader-friendly identifier (I didn't make it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `exists` for all conditions except the one on the `D` table:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM c JOIN
     (SELECT d.rownum, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             SUM(CASE WHEN d.type = 'Member' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as num_members
      FROM t
      GROUP BY d.rownum
     ) d
     ON c.rownum = d.rownum
WHERE c.status <> 'closed' AND          
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE c.rowno = t.rowno) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM l WHERE c.rowno = l.rowno) AND
      . . .
```

I find `NOT EXISTS` is easier to follow logically.  I don't think there is a big performance difference between the two methods in SQL Server.

Comment: performance is definitely becoming an issue with this particular query - i'm finding that linking to the many tables is slowing things down quite a bit. I will try this way thank you!